How to deal with discontinuity functions with finite difference methods in Python?
I am currently trying to price an option using finite difference methods + some stochastic model (Heston for people familiar with financial engineering).
My function / payoff is discontinuous making finite difference pricing method very unstable.
def payoff_rcb(S,autocall_barriere,dip_barriere,coupon):
    if S >= autocall_barriere:
        return 100 + coupon
    elif S >= dip_barriere:
        return 100
    else:
        return S

#conditions aux limites
payoff_maturity = np.vectorize(lambda x : payoff_rcb(x,autocall_barriere,dip_barriere,coupon))
for v in range(0,Nv):
    matrix_option_price[Nt-1,:,v] = payoff_maturity(S_vec)

#parameters
beta = 1.5
theta = 0.20
mu = 0.08
r = 0.05

# increments
dt = T_vec[1] - T_vec[0]
ds = S_vec[1] - S_vec[0]
dv = V_vec[1] - V_vec[0]

# apply DF method for T-1 option value being
for t in range(1,Nt):
    for s in range(1,Ns-1):
        for v in range(1,Nv-1):

            #compute derivatives
            dc_ds = ( matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v] - matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s-1,v] ) / (1* ds)
            dc_dv = ( matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v] - matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v-1] ) / (1 * dv)
            d2c_ds2 = ( matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s+1,v] - 2 * matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v] + matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s-1,v] ) / (ds**2)
            d2c_dv2 = ( matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v+1] - 2 * matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v] + matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v-1] ) / (dv**2)

            #terms for EDP
            block_1 = 0.5 * V_vec[v] * (S_vec[s]**2) * d2c_ds2
            block_2 = 0.5 * theta * V_vec[v] * d2c_dv2
            block_3 = mu * S_vec[s] * dc_ds
            block_4 = theta * (beta - V_vec[v]) * dc_dv
            block_5 = r * matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v]
            block = block_1 + block_2 + block_3 + block_4 - block_5

            #final option value at (s,v) for backward computation
            matrix_option_price[Nt-t-1,s,v] = matrix_option_price[Nt-t,s,v] + dt * block

I can see by printing 2D matrix at each points 't' that the issue (massive numbers) are spreading from where the discountinuity in the payoff is happening.
I can still solve the issue using matrices and LU method but want to be able to use a 3D matrix and solving point by point.
